# PHPUnit isolated world

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd, phpunit

I've just started using PHPUnit. Before this, I've used RSpec and Cucumber and their isolated environment where really nice.
I've done my first phpunit test and created 2 mock class, wondering if they will remain in my next test and, as I presumed, they will.

Now, I'm thinking of using a really specific namespace for all this helpers, something like this:

```
<?php
namespace Subject;

class FirstDependency { /* ... */ }
class TestableSubject extends \Subject { /* ... */ }

class SubjectTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    /* tests */
}
```

Is there any better solution to avoid namespace cluttering?

I take the opportunity for another question: which is faster between a method call and a dynamic class instantiation (`$s = 'MyClass'; $c = new $s;`)?
Actually when I've a dependencies I just put it on a method, such us `new_something()` and then test a child class `TestableSubject` with that method overridden.
Again, any better way to do this?

Comment: So you keep your tests together with implementations? "which is faster" --- it does not matter. "any better way to do this" --- yes, pass dependency explicitly (through a method or a constructor). "created 2 mock class" --- you usually create mock **objects**, not classes.

Comment: No, I don't. Test and implementations area obviously in their own files. What I put together is the test unit and its helpers, such as `FirstDependency` mock **class**. I've already read about PHPUnit's mock utilities, but for now I feel more comfortable with my own.

Comment: if you keep them separately - it's not clear what exact problem you have with namespaces. "any better way to do this", "I feel more comfortable with my own" --- why do you ask then?

Comment: The last phrase was referred to PHPUnit's mock utilities, not the "test unit's world isolation" matter. When I run a testsuite, if I declare an helper class in testA, it will also present in any subsequent testB. However, when you have to create new object of an external class, how do you manage this kind of dependencies?

Comment: you create a mock **object** instead (as in any other testing environment and language, including, but not limited by: javascript, java, c#). And then you pass **an object** as an explicit dependency using any dependency injection technique you like (setter injection, constructor injection or even property injection using reflection)

Comment: You don't understand. See this example: http://codeshare.io/aWk6k

Comment: I do understand. Either: a) Modify your code to be able to test it (if you followed *tdd* you wouldn't be in stuck actually). b) create a partial mock (which is still an object).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57880/discussion-between-iazel-and-zerkms).